# Will bringing my mother in visitor visa to Germany cause any problems when I try to bring prove her hardship?

Tags: visa, germany, blue-card, dependent-visa

I am planning to bring my mother in visitor visa to Germany for a couple of months. At the moment she is staying with my wife in Sri Lanka. Later I planned to file a hardship case and see if I can prove that she is dependent on me to try to bring her for a long stay. Because my wife will soon join me here and mom will be alone when that happens. She is 61 and widowed. She also doesn't speak the majority language in my country and is dependent on me for a living and she is emotionally dependent on me. So it'd be really helpful for her if I can bring her on a long stay.

Comment: She could start learning the majority language.  If she does move to Germany, she should learn German - my great-grandmother moved to South Africa at about your mother's age, and never bothered to learn English.  This was a mistake as she lived to over 100.  Also, I'm 60, and not too old to learn a new language.  This is a comment, because it doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: Apart from the language, as I said she is entirely dependent on me emotionally. And in our country we are super close to our parents and don't move away from them. But the living for people who speak our language has become difficult there. All kinds of rights and political problems. That's why I had to move out and I would like my mom to be safe with me as well. That's the context